# Get confused with Responsive menu with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My responsove menu works well in mobile menu, but I have one problem that when I resize browser back to large screen size. the mobile menu still appear. Does anybody know why?

Here is my code :

CSS

```
.main-navigation ul {
    z-index: 999;
    float: right;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.main-navigation ul>li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.main-navigation ul>li a {
    color: #555;
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 42px;
    margin-left: .5em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    position: relative;
}

.main-navigation ul>li ul {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity .1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity .1s ease-in;
    transition: opacity .1s ease-in;
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    left: -1em;
}

.main-navigation ul>li ul li {
    float: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background: #f9f9f9;
}

.main-navigation ul>li ul li a {
    padding: 0 1em;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.main-navigation ul>li ul li a::before {
    content: '';
}

.main-navigation ul>li ul li ul {
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: -1px;
    height: 21px;
    line-height: 21px;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity .1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity .1s ease-in;
    transition: opacity .1s ease-in;
}

.main-navigation ul>li:hover>ul {
    opacity: 10;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    visibility: visible;
}

.main-navigation ul>li:hover>a {
    color: #e74c3c;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:479px) {


.main-navigation ul {
    z-index: 999;
    float: right;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.main-navigation ul>li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.main-navigation ul>li a {
    color: #555;
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 42px;
    margin-left: .5em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    position: relative;
}

.main-navigation ul>li ul {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity .1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity .1s ease-in;
    transition: opacity .1s ease-in;
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    left: -1em;
}

.main-navigation ul>li ul li {
    float: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background: #f9f9f9;
}

.main-navigation ul>li ul li a {
    padding: 0 1em;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.main-navigation ul>li ul li a::before {
    content: '';
}

.main-navigation ul>li ul li ul {
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: -1px;
    height: 21px;
    line-height: 21px;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity .1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity .1s ease-in;
    transition: opacity .1s ease-in;
}

.main-navigation ul>li:hover ul {
    opacity: 10;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    visibility: visible;
}

.main-navigation ul>li:hover>a {
    color: #e74c3c;
}
```

}

HTML :

```
<a href="#" id="rwd-nav-btn" >&#9776;</a>
<div class="rwd-nav"></div> <!-- end rwd-nav -->

<nav class="main-navigation">

                            <ul class="fr">
                                <li><a href="">home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">articles</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">portfolio</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">dropdown</a>

                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="">home</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">articles</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">portfolio</a></li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="">dropdown</a>

                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="">home</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="">articles</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="">portfolio</a></li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="">dropdown</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li><a href="">about</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="">about</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
                            </ul>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">about</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
                    </ul>   
                    </nav>
```

jQuery :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.main-navigation ul:first-child').clone().appendTo('.rwd-nav');


    jQuery('#rwd-nav-btn').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery('.rwd-nav').slideToggle();
    });
```

Comment: you have neither posted the **css media queries** nor the respective **js code**.

Comment: in provided code, I didn't see any code part that gets activated on Change of Browser screen. either you should use javascript's on resize or use CSS media filter to filter your CSS on different screen size.

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle example. i dont see how this code can make a responsive menu.

Comment: Sorry eveyone. I forgot to add Media queries. Now I already Edited.

Answer (score 0):

There is no code which hides the menu. Instead of `slideToggle`, I suggest to add/remove a class like "closed" and "open" and set `mymenu.closed` to `display:none` and inside the media query set `mymenu.open` to `display:block`